# How the following code is working without using .live() or .on() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following function which I am calling after the Ajax completes:

```
function name(results)
{       
    var str='';

    str+='<div id="newDiv"></div>';
    str+='<input type="text" value="'+results.name+'" id="newTextbox"></input>'; 

   $('#otherDiv').html(str);  
}
```

Then I used `newDiv` and `newTextbox` some where like

```
$('#newDiv').html('Example Text');
```

it works well for me. But when I use

```
$('#newTextbox').click(function(){
     alert('CLICK WITHOUT LIVE');
});
```

it is not working. Then I changed it to:

```
$('#newTextbox').live("click",function(){
     alert('CLICK WITH LIVE');
});
```

Then it is working for me.

My question is  both (`newDiv`, `newTextbox`) are created dynamically.

Why is `$('#newDiv').html('Example Text');` working without using live, but click event is not working for `newTextbox`?

Comment: _Then i used newDiv and newTextbox some where_ .. where ?

Comment: in another function after this function is completed.In that i used the above statements

Comment: What are you doing with the `str` variable after that? With the code shown it's just a local variable that is never used for anything. At what point are you trying to access those elements?

Comment: and that another function is called from inside ajax success ?

Comment: now i updated my code.see it once

Comment: @undefined no i dont have

Comment: Do you get any error message? There shouldn't be any ending tag for the `input` element.

Comment: sorry.Sysntax problems is ok for me.But i need the reason for this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question, I want to tell you that :

> A string containing a JavaScript event type, such as "click" or
>   "keydown." As of jQuery the string can contain multiple,
>   space-separated event types or custom event names.

Here `.click` is an event and `.html` is not an event.

So your `.html`  function is working well without using `.live` function but `.click` is an event that is bind with the Selectors and it is created dynamically that's why you need to use the `.live` or `.on` function to bind the event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("click", "#newTextbox", function() {
    alert('CLICK WITHOUT LIVE');
});
```

You can use `on` function to bind event for dynamically added element